# Embedded JW Player causes CLS (only when it autoplays

Tags: iframe, jwplayer, cls

An JW Player instance embedded in an iframe is producing CLS when autoplayed. A div inside the iframe (some measurements indicate a div with the classes jw-controls jw-reset) seems to start rendered with a top position and the height of the video container, then it reduces size and changes position.

Is there a way to prevent this?

I've tried adding some inline style and attributes to the iframe element (position, width), but that didn't work.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Paste this html into a html document and open it in Google Chrome.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="post__content-wrapper">
        <div class="iframe_wrapper"><iframe style="position: relative" width="100%" height="400" class="iframe__video"
                frameborder="0" src="https://www.starmag.com/player/index/114370/3/13">
            </iframe></div>
        <figcaption class="post__excerpt"> Dans la réserve de Sabi Sand Game, en Afrique du Sud, un homme est à la
            recherche de lions. Mais il va tomber sur les félins plus vite qu'il ne le pensait ! </figcaption>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Open DevTools and toggle device view on.
3. Check CLS issues in either the Performance tab->Start profiling and reload the page->Experience->CLS
   [image]

or the Performance Insights (lab) tab -> Measure page load-Insights->Cumulative Layout Shift
[image]

Also, the issue can be found in the production environment on this site:
https://www.starmag.com/video/videos-du-jour/les-calculs-sont-pas-bons-kevin-la-video-humoristique-dines-reg-fait-le-buzz-352768.html
CLS will be detected on mobile, on the pages that contain autoplaying video

#### Environment

- Google Chrome Version 113.0.5672.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)